# how to get a jQuery UI Datepicker date value in a different format than it's displayed?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I need it to display the regular MM/DD/YY format in the inputbox, but I need the date formatted to YYYY-MM-DD to insert into the DB.
If you care to give some example code, it can be on form submission event or on a datepicker's event like when the user selects a date.
Thanks

Comment: Unless you are using PHP, you don't need the date formatted for insertion into the database; you need to convert it whatever representation is required to submit it as a command parameter (e.g., DateTime for C#). Whatever the case, you shouldn't be doing any munging for the database's benefit on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change accordingly, for instace change click for submit:

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />


<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


$('#conbutton').click(function() {

    var changeformat= $( "#datepicker" ).val();
    var arraydates = changeformat.split("/");
    var newdate =  arraydates[2]+"-"+arraydates[0]+"-"+arraydates[1];
    alert(newdate);

});


     });
</script>

</head>
<body>


 <input id="datepicker" type="text">
 <button id="conbutton"  >convert</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/gg5gt/2/